# awk: get maximum values and the fields that correspond to the values

Tags: bash, awk

Here are ways to get the maximum/minimum values of a row using awk.

[AWK - find min value of each row with arbitrary size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526220/awk-find-min-value-of-each-row-with-arbitrary-size)

However, I would need to go one step further by printing the fields that hold the max/min values. For example, the max value for a row is 100 and it is located at $13, so the output should be 100 and 13. Is this beyond awk?

Comment: Just save the field number into a separate variable and update it when you find a new maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
awk '{max=$1;c=1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i>max){c=i;max=$i} printf "max:%s, column:%s\n",max, c}'
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "1 4 3 2 6 5 8"|awk '{max=$1;c=1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i>max){c=i;max=$i} printf "max:%s, column:%s\n",max, c}' 
max:8, column:7
```

Comment: I think, the contents of the `END` section are to be done per line. So, need to be moved just after for loop body.

Comment: Right approach but you don't need 2 variables, just `c` and `$c` (maybe rename to `maxc` or something): `awk '{maxc=1;for(c=2;c<=NF;c++)if($c>$maxc){maxc=c} printf "max:%s, column:%s\n",$maxc, maxc}'`